# Magento - How do I get the ID for an attribute option?

Tags: php, magento

Here is my current code which gives me the options of my attribute:

```
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', '158');
foreach ( $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false) as $option){
//$attributeArray[$option['value']] = $option['label'];
echo"<li><a href=\"".Mage::getURL()."catalogsearch/advanced/result/?nf_featires[]=".$option['label']."\">".$option['label']."</li>";

}
```

I am trying to link them up but I need the option ID in order to have the search page return results. How do I pull the option ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer didn't work Jonathan. What did work was `$option['value']` and it required me changing `getAllOptions(false)` to `getAllOptions(true)`

Comment: This gets the option value not the option id.

Answer (score 0):

`$option['option_id']` or `$option->getOptionId()` should work

Answer (score 0):

$option['value'] gets you the option id, have a look at Alan Storms answer in [How do I filter a collection by a YesNo type attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711718/how-do-i-filter-a-collection-by-a-yesno-type-attribute)