# Magento filter products by custom attributes

Tags: magento-1.7

I think I tried everything and read everything, but I'm pretty confused about filtering product collection in Magento. I created a new product attribute 'syncron_state', but I can't manage to filter the product_collection by this filter. When I try to filter by core attributes it works and that's clear.

```
$productsCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('eq' => '000001'))
->setCurPage(1)->setPageSize(10)
->load();
```

But if I try to filter by my attribute I get nothing.

```
$productsCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
->addAttributeToFilter('syncron_state', array('eq' => '1'))
->setCurPage(1)->setPageSize(10)
->load();
```

The syncron_state is a Yes/No Attribute, as far as I know it has an integer value in database (but i tried true/false and yes/no in filtering also).

I tried all versions of addAttributeToFilter and AddFieldToFilter.

Oh, and I'm fighting with Magento 1.7.0.0

Comment: Hm, your collection using `syncron_state` as filter should work as expected for products having `syncron_state == yes`. Did you also add the `syncron_state` attribute to the proper attribute set? That is, have you added the new attribute to the specific attribute set the products in question are using? And just to make sure, did you set the `syncron_state` attribute of at least one of your products to `Yes` and saved the product?

Comment: Oh my God... everything was correct except that "set the syncron_state attribute of at least one of your products to Yes" thing. I throw almost a full workday into the garbage. Thank you very much. If you write that things in answer I can accept it and it could help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your collection using `syncron_state` as a filter *should* work as expected, at least for products having `syncron_state` set to `yes`.

One possible reason for not getting products would be, that you failed to add the new `syncron_state` attribute to the proper attribute set (which is a must).

Another possible reason would be, that you simply forgot to set the `syncron_state` attribute of at least one product to `Yes`.